# Amazon EC2: Public IP changes at reboot

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-ec2, ip

Im using Amazon EC2 to host a few websites on a single instance. 
From time to time I need to rescale my instance type. This requires a shut-down of the instance, and after relaunch the instance have gotten a new public IP address. 
This requires me to change the DNS config (very annoying), which takes up to 12 hours before it works.

Im pretty sure that im doing something wrong here, so my question is: Whats the best approach?

Comment: I believe that you should use an elastic IP and assign this to your EC2 instance.

Comment: That looks right. Feel free to submit your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An **Elastic IP** can be assigned to an instance. This is **not** ephemeral like the Public IP assigned to the instance and thus will be maintained across resizes and can be re-assigned to different instances.

Information on setting this up can be found here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-ip-addressing.html#vpc-eips